# How can I parse GCIDE xml files with Java?

Tags: java, xml

I am new to XML parsing, and I am having hard time parsing GCIDE xmls. I just need the headword with tag `<hw></hw>` and the definition field. I kinda accomplished that, but how can I parse the `<def>` elements with multiple meanings which are inside `<sn>` tag?

here is the link of xml files.
http://www.ibiblio.org/webster/#the_text_files

The code I have written so far
http://pastebin.com/mqdc5z0G

My code is having problem beacause the xml tags are not uniform I think.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the code you have written so far.

Comment: the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740690/how-to-search-inside-gcide-xml-using-php